# How to test when log occurs on Exception

Tags: java, mockito

How do I test that the following code will perform the logging statement when `Exception` is thrown, using `Mockito`?

```
public void cleanUp() {    
    for (Map.Entry<String, Connection> connection : dbConnectionMap.entrySet()) {
       try {
           if (connection.getValue() != null) {
              connection.getValue().close();
           }
       }catch (Exception e) {
           LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Exception when closing database connection: ", e);
       }
    }
    reset();
}
```

Comment: You typically cannot mock the logger if this is a static method, but depending on the log framework used you can redirect its output in a stringbuffer (or you create a file and validate its content)

Comment: I found this while searching a similar problem: https://slackhacker.com/2009/12/08/testing-logging-behaviour-in-four-code-lines-flat/. I'm not sure if this will help though.